# Singleton Collections in Java Trove

Tags: java, trove4j

Is there anything similar in Trove to Java's `Collections.singleton`, `Collections.singletonList`, or `singletonMap`?

I'm working in a application that uses many of the trove collections to reduce memory foot print. However, I have been unable to find any singleton Trove collections. For example, creating a `TLongHashSet` with 1 element using the default constructor will result in a `TLongHashSet` with an underlying array of 23 elements. Even when specifying the initial size and load factor as 1 and 1 will still result in an underlying array of 5 elements (Trove's the lowest prime is 5 based on `gnu.trove.impl.PrimeFinder`). In additional to the underlying array there are additional class variables that could be removed for a singleton implementation.

Comment: Why do you think you need a singleton collection?

Comment: @JimGarrison for the same reasons that the Java singleton collections exist. For my use case, I'm working with methods that return Trove collections. The result may only contain a single element. I would like to use a Trove singleton collection to reduce memory usage. Granted, the memory savings will be minimal. But if there are existing functions/classes that support trove singletons, I might as well use them.

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't in the current version of Trove.

You can use [Koloboke collections (ex. HFTC)](https://github.com/OpenHFT/hftc) to reduce memory footprint even more, than with Trove, but assign them to variables/fields of parental JCF interface (e. g. `java.util.Map`), which interoperate well with JCF's `Collections.singleton*` implementations.

Comment: KFTC looks interesting. Do you know of any benchmarks comparing it against Trove?